# Reading TCP stream by one byte in rust

Tags: rust

I want to read bytes from a TCP Stream but if I read it by 100 or 1000 bytes I can cut some bytes of the next request. So I decided to read stream by one byte like this:

```
let mut res_buf = vec![];
loop {
  let mut buf = vec![0; 1];
  let n = match self.read(&mut buf) {
    Err(e) => {
      match e.kind() {
          io::ErrorKind::WouldBlock => {
              continue;
          },
          _ => panic!("Got an error: {}", e),
      }
    },
    Ok(m) => {
        if m == 0 {
            return Err(Error::new(ErrorKind::BrokenPipe, "broken"))
        }
        m
    },
  };
  buf.truncate(n);
  res_buf.extend(buf.iter());

  let stringed = String::from_utf8_lossy(&res_buf);
  if stringed.contains("\r\n\r\n") {
    // END OF PART

    return Ok(stringed.to_string());
  }
}
```

It fires read calls on every byte. Is this wrong and inefficient?

Comment: @mkrieger1 no, I want to read all bytes of the message but I want to read them by one

Comment: But it will cause tons of i/o read calls. I mean is there nothing wrong with it?

Comment: Wrap the TCP stream in a `std::io::BufReader`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.Reading by one byte is good if you read from the "pure" memory(std::io::Cursor over a Vec or array etc.) and bad if this reading triggers a syscall (file, socket etc.). In the latter case you better should wrap it in a BufReader, but in your code you will be loosing bytes (hold in BufReader and not read by your function) on return. Consider refactor your code, for example so you pass the res_buf for processing the whole request to another thread.

2.Your **if stringed.contains("\r\n\r\n")** very probably should be **ends_with("\r\n\r\n")**

3.You do not need a heap allocated buffer here:

```
let mut byte = 0 as u8;
self.read(std::slice::from_mut(&mut byte));
```

Comment: Thanks. I heard of BufReader but I thought there could be some more things I could use for this case